# DNS Server Down can't receive email from google apps

Tags: domain-name-system, g-suite

If DNS is down would it make sense that I cannot receive e-mail for that domain?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you mean that your name servers are down then yes, you won't be able to recieve email as sending MTA's will not be able to find your MX record.

Comment: Just a quick followup, if people tried to send me email when server is down, will I receive them later.

Comment: I guess it depends on the sending MTA and how they handle not being able to contact your name servers. Some may treat it as a transient failure and try again later while others may treat it as a permanent failure and delete the email.

Answer (score 1):

In answer to your follow-up question: there is a very good chance that that mail sent while your server is off-line will be lost. To help with this try an MX backup service like dnsmadeeasy.com, they will store your email while your system is not available and start sending them when your system is back online. This has saved me every time there is a power outage or company move.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe. If your receiving server checks forward/reverse DNS for the domain before accepting e-mail, then yes, you couldn't receive their e-mail while their DNS is down.